# MYSQL - if not in category and regex matches content then: (add to category and delete from other category)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, categories

I want to add posts to a category and remove from another if conditions are met: regex matches content and is not in a certain category.

so in points:

Actions:

- add posts to category A
- remove those posts from category B

If Conditions:

- post content matches certain regex
- not in category C

I have two snippets of SQL code which I am having trouble combining.

**---snippet 1--- add to category based on regex in post ------**

```
REPLACE INTO wp_term_relationships (term_taxonomy_id, object_id) SELECT '141',  ID
FROM  `wp_posts` 
   WHERE (post_title REGEXP '((?<!\\b[A-Z]|\\b[A-Z][A-Z])\\$|\\bAU?\\$|CA?N?\\$)[^\\d\\r\\n]?((?:\\d{1,10}[,. ])*\\d{1,10})[ .]?(k)?|((?:\\d{1,10}[,. ])*\\d{1,10})[ .]?(k)? ?(?:USD?\\b|dollar|cash|\\bbucks\\b|GBP|EURO?S?\\b|AUD\\b|CAD\\b|INR\\b)' 
    OR post_content REGEXP '((?<!\\b[A-Z]|\\b[A-Z][A-Z])\\$|\\bAU?\\$|CA?N?\\$)[^\\d\\r\\n]?((?:\\d{1,10}[,. ])*\\d{1,10})[ .]?(k)?|((?:\\d{1,10}[,. ])*\\d{1,10})[ .]?(k)? ?(?:USD?\\b|dollar|cash|\\bbucks\\b|GBP|EURO?S?\\b|AUD\\b|CAD\\b|INR\\b)')
   AND (post_type = 'post' )
```

**---snippet 2--- remove posts from a category that exist in another category ------**

```
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships 
  WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 160 #@CategoryID
  AND object_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT object_id FROM (SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships) AS tr2 
       WHERE tr2.term_taxonomy_id = 161); #@OtherCategoryID
```

snippet 2 is all I could find close enough to what I want to do.

Cant seem to get it all working together in one statement

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is with **transactions.**  (You must use a table-architecture that supports them, and these days you probably do.)

A "transaction" is an **atomic** operation:  either "everything happens at once" (`COMMIT`), "or nothing does" (`ROLLBACK`).  Now, within the transaction, you can perform multiple queries to get the work done, and other users will not see the intermediate states.  When you commit your transaction, they see the finished result appear instantaneously – unless they're in the middle of a transaction, too.

This is an intentionally simplistic explanation ... but you get the idea. Now you don't have to "get it all done in one query."